# How to change UIButton backgroundimage while clicking same UIbutton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I am using **UIButton** with xib backgroundImage is **check_box_off.png**, while clicking the 
atmbtn backgroundImage change to **check_box_on.png** meanwhile **NSLog** printing **yesString** and again clicking atmbtn there is no change in backgroundImage same **check_box_on.png** meanwhile NSLog Printing same **yesString** only.. again and again clinking the atmbutton same only happening..

```
- (IBAction)atmAction:(id)sender{  
    if( [atmbtn backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] ==
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_on.png"] ) {
       [atmbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_off.png"] 
               forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

        noString = @"No"; 
        NSLog(@"atm=%@",noString);
    } else if( [atmbtn backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] ==
                [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_off.png"]) {

        [atmbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_on.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];

         yesString = @"Yes";
         NSLog(@"atm = %@",yesString);
     }
}
```

> output:
>
> NSLog Print:
>
> atm=Yes
>
> atm=Yes
>
> atm=Yes

how Could I resolve this? Please Share your Ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
[atmbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a **BOOL variable** instead of if condition

**.h file**

```
BOOL _isClicked;
```

**.m file**

```
-(IBAction)atmAction:(id)sender{  

    if(!isClicked){

       [atmbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_off.png"]
               forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
        _isClicked = YES;      

     } else {

         [atmbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_on.png"]
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
          _isClicked = NO;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `UIImage` and you are checking the `backgroundImage`.

Try

```
if([atmbtn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] ==
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_on.png"])
```

instead of

```
if([atmbtn backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal] ==
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_on.png"])
```

Comment: it's working good ... I was set check_box_off.png image as a UIButton backgroundImage but I tried for image path.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
    [atmbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_off.png"]
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [atmbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_on.png"]
                    forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Where `atmbtn` is the outlet of the button in your xib.

Comment: it's working good ... I was set check_box_off.png image as a UIButton backgroundImage but I tried for image path. I used [atmbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_off.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal]; instead of [atmbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_off.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

Hi try `isEqual` method rather then `==` because you are comparing objects not values. Try this:

```
-(IBAction)atmAction:(id)sender{

    if([[atmbtn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] 
          isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_on.png"]] ) {

        [atmbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_off.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        noString = @"No";
        NSLog(@"atm = %@",noString);

    } else if( [[atmbtn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] 
                  isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_off.png"]] ){

        [atmbtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_box_on.png"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        yesString = @"Yes";
        NSLog(@"atm = %@",yesString);
    }
}
```