# Toggle Button Background image on button released

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to be able to toggle the background image of button back and forth on the button being released.
I have programmatically added the button to my view controller and can get it to change to the image during it being pressed. But am unsure as to how I should handle once released.

Please help! Would be much appreciated.
Below is the code used in my viewDidLoad.

```
UIButton *shareButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
// position in the parent view and set the size of the button
shareButton.frame = CGRectMake(51, 216, 46, 36);
[shareButton setTitle:@"Share" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// Add image to button for normal state
UIImage * shareImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noninverted_19.png"];
[shareButton setImage:shareImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// Add image to button for pressed state
UIImage * shareImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"inverted_19.png"];
[shareButton setImage:shareImage2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
// add targets and actions
[shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitBookingButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
// add to a some parent view.
[eventScroller addSubview:shareButton];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a bool `_firstImg`, and then try this code (I got some of it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13155317/3769927))

```
- (IBAction)submitBookingButtonPressed:(UIButton)sender {
    NSString *imageName = @"image_1"
    if (!_firstImg) {
        imageName = @"image_2"
    }
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _firstImg = !_firstImg
}
```

Replace `image_1` and `image_2` with whatever the names of the images are.

Note that I haven't tested this, so you might need to modify some of the syntax.

Comment: Thank you, helped but it's left the first image there and I can't seem to get rid of it. Created a toggle that adds and takes away the second image on-top of the button.

Comment: @JoshHyatt I see. In that case, replace `setBackgroundImage` with just `setImage`. My bad. I'll just update the answer.

Comment: @JoshHyatt Awesome! Do mark the answer as correct so that other people see this too.